# JS OR operator not working with v-bind Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use a javascript `||` (or) operator with `v-bind` on a button in Vue JS, this isn't working:

```
v-bind:disabled="searchInput.length == '' || !selectValue"
```

Comment: Well it's probably working, just not doing what you're expecting... for example, `length` returns a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably because you're checking the length property of a string which should be a number. Try ..

`v-bind:disabled="searchInput.length == 0 || !selectValue"`